# How to reduce leaves length for fitting labels in R dendrogram?

Tags: r, hcluster

I produced a cluster with `hcluster`.
[original dendogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGZzg.png).

For formatting purposes I used `as.dendogram`. When I did that my labels were cut of.
[vertical dendogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sizv7.jpg)

Even more by the horizontal orientation. The one I need.
[horizontal dendogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdVS7.jpg)

The problem does not seams to be in margins since (for the horizontal one) I used `par(oma = c(0, 0, 0, 8)` with not label effect. It only a reduced my margins but not give more room for labels names. How can I make sure that the plot shows the entire model names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably change `mar` and not `oma` in `par()`:

```
mm <- matrix(rnorm(20), ncol = 4)
colnames(mm) <- c("leaf1", "leaf2", "leaf3", "very_long_leaf_realy")

# compare:
plot(as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(mm)))), horiz = TRUE)

# with:
oldpar <- par(mar = c(5, 4 ,4 , 8))
plot(as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(mm)))), horiz = TRUE)
par(oldpar) # restoring ploting parameters
```